# What is the perl's equivalent of repr in python/ruby's inspect method

Tags: perl, tostring, representation

What is the perl's equivalent of repr in python/ruby's inspect method?

(I'm asking so I can use it for doing print debugging)

Comment: Looks like you already got a good answer, but, for future reference, it's generally a good idea to include a description of what the desired function does so that those who know (in this case) Perl, but aren't familiar with Python/Ruby, will still be able to help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are looking for `Data::Dumper`; see [the documentation](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Data%3a%3aDumper) for some examples.

Comment: Consider [`Data::Dump`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Data::Dump) for prettier printing.

Comment: Consider [Data::Dump::Streamer](http://p3rl.org/Data::Dump::Streamer) for prettier printing and key sorting and deparsing subroutines by default and showing variable names.